# Where could we put `Office.onReady()` to make sure Office.js could fully load every time

Tags: reactjs, ms-office, office-js, dvajs

I'm debugging an Excel add-in built in React. Previously, the developer coded the app as if it was a website rather than an Excel add-in, and did not pay attention to Office.js. As a result, when we run it in Excel, we have the famous error `Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this functionality, try reloading this page.`

[image]

I searched for `Office.onReady` and `Office.initialize` in the whole project, I did not find them.

Here is `frontend/src/index.tsx`, where [dva](https://github.com/dvajs/dvahttps://github.com/dvajs/dva) is a "framework based on redux, redux-saga and react-router (Inspired by elm and choo)".

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import dva from 'dva';
import './index.css';
import router from './router';
import AuthModel from './models/auth';
import SubscribtionModel from './models/subscription';
import AppModel from './models/app';
import { initializeIcons } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icons';

//@ts-ignore
//import createLoading from 'dva-loading';

// 1. Initialize
const app = dva();
//app.use(createLoading());

// 2. Plugins
// app.use({});

// 3. Model
//@ts-ignore
app.model(AuthModel);
app.model(SubscribtionModel)
app.model(AppModel);
// 4. Router
//@ts-ignore
app.router(router);

// 5. Start
app.start('#root');

initializeIcons();
```

Does anyone know where I should put `Office.onReady()` such that we could make sure Office.js can fully load every time the add-in is launched?

**Edit 1:**

I tried to mimic [this file](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/06751273095a1ab54c0c644d212b7a30c904824a/packages/common/src/components/PageSwitcher/index.tsx) and changed one of my `index.tsx` to

```
  render() {
    const { items, farItems } = this.props;

    console.log("Here is Office:");
    console.log(Office);

    return (
      <AwaitPromiseThenRender
        promise={Promise.resolve().then(async () => {
              await Office.onReady();
        })}
      >
        <CommonHeader
          items={items.map((item: IHeaderItem) => this.renderItem(item))}
          farItems={farItems.map((item: IHeaderItem) => this.renderItem(item))}
        />
      </AwaitPromiseThenRender>
    );
  }
```

It returned a TypeScript error: `Property 'onReady' does not exist on type 'typeof Office'.  TS2339`, whereas the object `Office` is well printed in the console. Does anyone have any idea of the problem?

**Edit 2:**

I tried to add the following code in my `frontend/src/index.tsx` above. It still returned `Property 'onReady' does not exist on type 'typeof Office'.  TS2339`.

```
export function render(oldRender: () => void) {
    Office.onReady((reason: any) => {
      oldRender();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Yeoman generator? if you are using Yeoman generator, you can put office.onReady in taskpane.js. here is the document for how to Initialize your Office Add-in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in
this is the link for building an add-in using yoeman generator (react) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react

Comment: @RaymondLu I‘m not using Yeoman. I don’t have taskpane.js. The project is big, it’s too late to change how it was generated.

Comment: in your manifest, you may have SourceLocation section, it states which HTML page your add-in is landing. you could put onReady in this page.

Comment: @RaymondLu I may have several buttons/entrypoints in this add-in. Is it possible to put onReady on a higher level, for example in this index.tsx?

Comment: What do you mean for several entry points to this add-in? does it mean several ribbon buttons? do you want all this entries navitate to the HTML page (which is the SourceLocation in manifest) that taskpane is landing?

Comment: @RaymondLu It means several ribbon buttons which lead to different pages.

Comment: Please see my update...

Comment: What about putting the `onReady` handler in a lifecycle component like `ComponentDidMount` and once the `onReady` handler fires, it can set something like `this.state.loading` to false. Then in your `render` function, you can render a loader until it is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in componentWillMount

```
async componentWillMount() {
 await hostApp.onReady();}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use class component,you can put it in `componentWillMount`.

If you use function component, you can put it in `Effect` hooks like this：

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    Office.onReady(function(info) {
      console.log(info);
      if (info.host === Office.HostType.Word) {
        console.log("hhhhhhhhhhh")
      }
      if (info.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC) {
        // Make minor layout changes in the task pane.
        console.log("ooooooooooooo")
      }
      console.log(`Office.js is now ready in ${info.host} on ${info.platform}`);
    });
  })
```